# Change Button scale on click

Tags: libgdx

I want for all the **Buttons** in my game to **scale down** when user **touch down** the button and goes back to **normal scale** as soon as on touch up.What should be be the best possible way.Just like functionality of button in COCOS-2d. 
I don't want to use **extra small image** for button down,if there is other alternative without using extra image.?

Second one is to produce some **sound** on **click**,I don't want to this in input listener of every button since sound is same for all buttons.How should i implement this in best possible way.

Thanks in advance.

// i just implement my custom class ,is there is other good way to implement.

```
public class ImprovedButton extends Button {    
    boolean isTouchDown=false;// is touch begin
    float originalWidth,originalHeight;     //actual size

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
        if( isPressed()) {
            if (!isTouchDown) {
                //play sound if any
                isTouchDown=true;
                originalHeight=getHeight();
                originalWidth=getWidth();
                setWidth(originalWidth*.95f);
                setHeight(originalHeight*.95f);
            }
        }
        else { //pressing is stopper if any
            if (isTouchDown) { 
                isTouchDown=false;
                setWidth(originalWidth);
                setHeight(originalHeight);
            }           
        }
    }    
}
```

one problem with this code is,pivot of scaling bottom left corner.How to set it as center.

Comment: If you make a function like this http://pastebin.com/s6YTXKaj - and call it instead of the draw method of the button, will it work? And are you sure that your isPressed and touchdown methods are good?

Comment: Check this this out  [LINK](http://pastebin.com/90D4uSqX) it work perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a custom class **ImprovedButton** extends from  Button class has additional functionality of Change in **SCALE** of button and plays **SOUND** on click .
 There is also a class of **ImprovedButtonStyle** has paramter of scale and sound.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.Drawable;

public class ImprovedButton extends Button {

    boolean isPressedOnce=false;//is press started or touchDown
    float originalWidth,originalHeight;
    private ImprovedButtonStyle istyle;

    public ImprovedButton() {
        super();
        this.istyle=new ImprovedButtonStyle();
    }    
    public ImprovedButton(Actor child, ImprovedButtonStyle style) {
        super(child, style);
        this.istyle=style;
    }    
    public ImprovedButton(Actor child, Skin skin, String styleName) {
        this(child,skin.get(styleName, ImprovedButtonStyle.class));         
    }    
    public ImprovedButton(Actor child, Skin skin) {
        this(child,skin.get(ImprovedButtonStyle.class));
    }    
    public ImprovedButton(ImprovedButtonStyle style) {
        super(style);
        this.istyle=style;
    }    
    public ImprovedButton(Drawable up, Drawable down, Drawable checked) {
        super(up, down, checked);
        istyle=new ImprovedButtonStyle();
    }    
    public ImprovedButton(Drawable up, Drawable down) {
        this(up, down,null);
    }    
    public ImprovedButton(Drawable up) {
        this(up,null,null);
    }    
    public ImprovedButton(Skin skin, String styleName) {
        super(skin, styleName);
        this.istyle=skin.get(ImprovedButtonStyle.class);    
    }    
    public ImprovedButton(Skin skin) {
        super(skin);
        setStyle(skin.get(ButtonStyle.class));    
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
        if( isPressed()) {
            if (!isPressedOnce) {                   
                if (istyle.sound!=null) {
                  istyle.sound.play();
                }
                isPressedOnce=true;
                originalHeight=getHeight();
                originalWidth=getWidth();
                setWidth(originalWidth-istyle.changeInWidth);
                setHeight(originalHeight-istyle.changeInHeight);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (isPressedOnce) {
                isPressedOnce=false;
                setWidth(originalWidth);
                setHeight(originalHeight);
            }           
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawBackground(Batch batch, float parentAlpha, float x,float y) {
         int offsetX=0;
         int offsetY=0;
         if(isPressed()){                
            offsetX=istyle.changeInWidth/2;
            offsetY=istyle.changeInHeight/2;
          }   
         super.drawBackground(batch, parentAlpha, x+offsetX, y+offsetY);
    }

    public static class ImprovedButtonStyle extends ButtonStyle{
        public int changeInWidth=2,changeInHeight=2;
        public Sound sound=null;
        public ImprovedButtonStyle() {
            super();
        }

    public ImprovedButtonStyle(ButtonStyle style,int changeInWidth,int changeInHeight,Sound sound) {
            super(style);
            this.changeInHeight=changeInHeight;
            this.changeInWidth=changeInWidth;
            this.sound=sound;
        }
    public ImprovedButtonStyle(Drawable up, Drawable down, Drawable checked) {
            super(up, down, checked);
        }
    public ImprovedButtonStyle(ImprovedButtonStyle style) {
            super(style);
            this.changeInHeight=style.changeInHeight;
            this.changeInWidth=style.changeInWidth;
            this.sound=style.sound;    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do the same thing on my games.

Make like your custom class for the button.

If you want you can increase the scale in the update method, so the button will scale smooth.
Look here, I wrote for you a example

```
public class CoolButton {
    private Sprite sprite; // the sprite that we are going to use to draw our button
    private float scale; // the scale of the button, 1 = full scale, 0.5 half, 2 = twice bigger, etc

    public CoolButton(Texture texture, float x, float y, float width, float height) {
        sprite = new Sprite(texture);
        sprite.setPosition(x, y);
        sprite.setSize(width, height);
        sprite.setOriginCenter();
        scale = 1;
    }

    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
        sprite.setScale(scale); // setting the scale and drawing the button
        sprite.draw(batch);
    }

    // this method should be called when the user touches the screen (don't forget to unproject the coords)
    public boolean touchDown(float x, float y) {
        if (sprite.getBoundingRectangle().contains(x, y)) { // if the button is touched
            scale = 0.7f;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // when you release the touch from the screen make the button back to its normal size
    public void touchUp() {
        scale = 1f;
    }
}
```

If you have any question please comment here.

Comment: So custom class is only option, basically i have to make custom class for button,text button and so on...No other way

Comment: Why do you need custom classes for all buttons? You can create one custom class and use it then for all buttons in your game.

Comment: i mean objects of TextButton,ImageTextButton classes.they are extented from button class.

Comment: hey paul, thanks for help ,i want coolbutton to be of type actor or button ,can you suggest something.

Comment: No problem! The actor class has a method /** Sets the scale for both X and Y */
 public void setScale (float scaleXY) {
  this.scaleX = scaleXY;
  this.scaleY = scaleXY;
 } , so instead of setting the sprite scale, set the actor scale. Have fun

Comment: hi paul,setting scale has no effect on button,i just add my code snippet which changes the scale but has problem of pivot,can you suggest something.

Comment: can you add your code to pastebind and link it here